# Set ENV variable for all commands in current directory in mac os

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, environment-variables

Is there a way to run all commands in current directory with some ENV variables predefined?

**Example of what I need:**

I put some file, say `.env` in my directory, with:

```
export SECRET='abcd123'
```

Then I run some command, say `rails c`, but in fact it should run as `SECRET='abcd123' rails c`. Of course, when I run command from another directory, this ENV variable should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory edit `.bashrc` and add the following function:

```
function dosecret()
{

    [ -f ./.env ] && source ./.env
    $*
    unset SECRET
}
```

To test run `source .bashrc`.

If there is a .env file in the current directory it is read (where `SECRET` variable is defined). The command is then run (`$*`) and after the command is complete the `SECRET` variable is unset.